# Why reflection and rotation are sufficient operations in dihedral group?

Tags: permutations, polygons

I know a bit of elementary group theory but please ignore *dihedral group* in the title and let's make it simple enough so a high student can read the question and the answer(s)...

Suppose we have a regular polygon with n vertices/sides.

Question: Show that by only rotation(s) and reflection(s) you can turn a given arrangement of numbers on the vertices to any other arrangement.

An incorrect answer: Because there is no other action that we can impose, except for reflection and rotation.

Is this answer a complete and rigorous proof for the question? How to prove the mentioned statement?

Edit - In gp-th language, prove that there always a function of the form $r^{n_1}s^{n_2} \dots r^{n_k}s^{n_k}$ such that any regular numbered polygon can be turned to another desired regular numbered polygon.

Comment: What does "an arrangement" mean here?

Comment: @Nick - It's a rigid motion on rigid shape, so you have consider changes that happens to other vertices/numbers.

Comment: @JohnMa - A given polygon with numbers on the vertices? I don't know better / technical words; I would appreciate if you help me with that or edit it. Thanks

Comment: Elements in $D_n$ are more restrictive ("A given polygon with numbers on the vertices" will correspond to elements in $S_n$). @L.G.

Comment: Number the vertices $1$ though $n$, with $1$ at the top. When you turn you given arrangement into another arrangement, the vertices must be in the same order or the reverse order (a reflection), and the label at the top may be changed (a rotation).

Comment: @ZachGershkoff - this is an excellent and 100% satisfactory answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer so this question doesn't look unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number the vertices $1$ through $n$, with $1$ at the top. When you turn you given arrangement into another arrangement, the vertices must be in the same order or the reverse order (a reflection), and the label at the top may be changed (a rotation). Therefore reflections and rotations are enough to give you all the possible symmetries of a polygon.